# Auto-filling text fields using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to create a bookmark that will auto fill a text field of a webpage. However; I'm receiving the following error code:

(program):1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of null

The code below is the element of the text field

```
<input type="text" name="test_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" id="text_id1">
```

The following is the bookmark code that I created:

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<DL>
    <DT><A  HREF="javascript:document.getElementById('text_id1').value='123';">test</A></DT>
</DL>
```

I am also trying to do this in Google Chrome.

Comment: It works fine on my machine~is there any other codes you have not shown?

Comment: Hey Jaycee, I may have found the issue. There was a warning on the website when I inspected the elements. "The page at (website) was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint (different webpage, same domain). This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection." Is there a way to auto-fill a form like this? (Is it "legal" to auto-fill a form like this?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the value of a text input - you need to use "value"

```
<a  HREF="javascript:document.getElementById('text_id1').value='123';">test</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after changing it I receive the following error: (program):1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: note you have code errors and your code as well - open p, dt  tags and no dd tags for example